# Logout and login with different account

Tags: support

I came to my friend house and logged in on his computer to SO. After that he can't log out from my account. We deleted all cookies, but still after pressing "Log In" and then "Use SO account" it's just logins to my account, without asking anything. It isn't logged in to the e-mail associated with that SO account. Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean your Stack Exchange OpenID account.

To log out of that, you'll need to go to [openid.stackexchange.com](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) and click the logout link.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks! Actually kinda strange scheme for logouting..

Comment: @Hate Well, they're technically 2 different accounts. The SE OpenID provider remembers you and that you approved your identity to be sent to Stack Overflow, so when you click the button it just goes ahead and logs you in. It's a convenience thing.